# single cocoa touch view to emulate terminal window for readline input and text output

Tags: objective-c, xcode, readline, terminal-emulator

I want to develop an iPad app which contains a single window that emulates a terminal for both input and output. The application (J) is a textbased programming language interpreter which does not really need a terminal window but can use readline from such a window for input. How can such a window/view be created in Xcode3 with Objective-C?

I have found the source code for readline on github.com, but I am not clear how a single window can be linked up for both the input and output.

Answer (score 1):

Basic idea is these.

Create UITextView and set the delegate to a subclass of UIViewController.

For input, implement this method (UITextViewDelegate protocol) in the subclass of UIViewController.
When got enough characters to process, do it.

```
– textView:shouldChangeTextInRange:replacementText:
```

For output, just add text to text property of NSTextView.